# Trying to understand a Haskell code example from the presentation "Why Do Monads Matter?"

Tags: haskell, monads

I was watching the [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q8xYFDYLeI) : " Why Do Monads Matter? "

I simplified one code [example](https://github.com/londonhaskell/londonhaskell-2012-10-24-why-do-monads-matter/blob/master/Pref.hs) which compiles and runs (please see below) but I still don't understand how it works.

More precisely: I don't understand the composePref function. According to the type definition it should take **2** parameters of Ize type and return one result of Ize type. (Ize means "whatdoyoucallit"/thingy/something in Hungarian.)

But it takes **three** parameters (f g x), could someone please explain how the composePref function works and what are the types of f, g, x, y and c ?

I have to admit that I am very beginner in Haskell. Maybe I don't understand how currying works in this case ?

```
module Dependence where
main = putStrLn (f "foo" cfg)
         where f = right `composePref` right `composePref` left
               cfg = 2

left :: Ize
left s = \i -> (repeatString i "< ") ++ s

right ::Ize
right s = \i -> s ++ (repeatString i " >")

repeatString :: Integer -> String -> String
repeatString i s = if (i <= 0)
                    then ""
                    else s ++ repeatString (i - 1) s

type Ize = String -> Integer -> String

composePref :: Ize -> Ize -> Ize
composePref f g x = \c -> let y =  (g x) c 
                          in       (f y) c
```

Produces output:

```
< < foo > > > >
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right in thinking that it is currying that allows this behavior.  If we look at the definition of `Ize`, it's just a type synonym for `String -> Integer -> String`.  If we plug this in to the type signature of `composePref`, we'd get

```
composePref :: (String -> Integer -> String) -> (String -> Integer -> String) -> (String -> Integer -> String)
```

(I hope you see now why a type alias was used, it greatly shortens the signature).  Since `->` in type signatures is right associative, it means that something like

```
a -> b -> c -> d
```

Is equivalent to

```
a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

So we can further simplify the signature to be (with some extra type aliases because I don't want to type them all)

```
type I = Integer
type S = String

composePref :: (S -> I -> S) -> (S -> I -> S) -> S -> I -> S
composePref f g x = \c -> ...
```

Then `f :: (S -> I -> S)`, `g :: (S -> I -> S)`, and `x :: S`.  I included the beginning of that labmda so that I could say that `c :: I`.  You could actually write this function as:

```
composePref :: Ize -> Ize -> Ize
composePref f g x c = let y = (g x) c in (f y) c
```

Which is also equivalent to

```
composePref f g x c = let y = g x c in f y c
-- (map show) [1, 2, 3] === map show [1, 2, 3]
```

Or

```
composePref f g x c = f (g x c) c
```

Or even

```
composePref f g = \x c -> f (g x c) c
```

These are all equivalent definitions of `composePref`.  I think the last might make it most clear that it's a function that takes two functions and returns a new function of the same type.

---

To try to make it even more clear, I'll write some **illegal syntax** with type annotations where you aren't really supposed to use them:

```
composePref (f :: Ize) (g :: Ize) = h
    where
        h :: Ize
        h (x :: String) (c :: Integer) =
            let (y :: String) = (g x) c
            in (f y) c
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, how does the compiler figure out all this ? Is this not ambigous without explicit type declaration on f g and x ? How does the compiler know that x is meant to be integer and not, say Int -> String? By looking at the expression in the function body ? Would the compiler complain if it could not infer the types of f g and x unambigously?

Comment: Yes, the compiler complains if there is any ambiguity.

Comment: @jhegedus The compiler uses some pretty intelligent algorithms to infer types.  If it can't figure it out, then it has no choice but to throw an error.  Since you've provided the function `composePref` a type signature of `Ize -> Ize -> Ize`, it reduces that down to the non-aliased long form and it can figure out that `x :: String` and `c :: Integer`.

Comment: And it's worth noting that it would have figured out the type of `composePref` without any type signature at all.

Comment: @augustss More accurately, it would have figured out **a** type signature for `composePref`, not **the** type signature.  It would have been able to assign it the more general type of `(a -> b -> c) -> (c - b -> d) -> a -> b -> d`.  If you say `a ~ String`, `b ~ Integer`, `a ~ c`, and `a ~ d`, then you'd get actual signature in this example.

Comment: @bheklilr I said "the", because it is the principal one.  So it's special.  :)  Admittedly, it's not the same one as the was given.

Comment: @augustss Your statement was in no way incorrect, I just wanted to make sure that it was clarified for someone who might not have a full understanding of the compiler's type-inferring abilities.

Answer (score 3):

If you expand the type of the last `Ize` in your function you get:

```
composePref :: Ize -> Ize -> (String -> Integer -> String)
composePref f g x = \c -> let y =  (g x) c 
                          in       (f y) c
```

which is the same as

```
composePref :: Ize -> Ize -> String -> Integer -> String
```

which is also the same as:

```
composePref :: Ize -> Ize -> String -> (Integer -> String)
```

which matches your definition of `composePref` more closely. Now `f` and `g` are both `Ize` while `x` is a String and `c` is an `Integer`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following alternative definition, if this makes things clearer

```
 composePref :: Ize -> Ize -> Ize
 composePref f g = \x -> \c -> let y =  (g x) c 
                               in       (f y) c
```